# Get the coordinate values from Map.Onclick in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, coordinates

I want to calculate a min cost path from a start point to a end point. Because the GEE has not provide the function, I have to code it by myself. The first step is to get the start and end point from the map by Map.Onclick function. How can I pass these points into the function for calculating min cost path?

```
function MinCostPath (){   
  var points = selectPoints.getValue();//wrong code here
  print(points); 
}

var selectPoints = ui.Select({
  items:['Start point', 'End point'], 
  
  placeholder: 'Choose input start or end point...',
  
  onChange: function(key) {
    print("The point needed to be clicked on the map is:" + key);
    
    Map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair');
  
    Map.onClick(function(coords) {
      var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
      print(point);
      
      var dot = ui.Map.Layer(point, {color: 'FF0000'},key);
    
      Map.layers().add(dot);
    
      Map.unlisten();
    });
  },
  });

var pathBtn = ui.Button({
  label: 'Caculating min cost path...',
  onClick: MinCostPath
});

var panel = ui.Panel([selectPoints,pathBtn]);
panel.style().set({
  width: '250px',
  position: 'bottom-left'
});

Map.add(panel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the selected points in a global variable:

```
var startPointKey = 'Start point'
var endPointKey = 'End point'
var selectedPoints = {}

function minCostPath() {   
  var startPoint = selectedPoints[startPointKey]
  var endPoint = selectedPoints[endPointKey]
  print('minCostPath', startPoint, endPoint)
}

var selectPoints = ui.Select({
  items:[startPointKey, endPointKey], 
  placeholder: 'Choose input start or end point...',
  onChange: function(key) {
    print("The point needed to be clicked on the map is:" + key);
    Map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair');
  
    Map.onClick(function(coords) {
      var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
      print(point);
      selectedPoints[key] = point
      if (Object.keys(selectedPoints).length === 2) {
        pathBtn.setDisabled(false) // Enable when there are two points selected
      }a
      
      var dot = ui.Map.Layer(point, {color: 'FF0000'},key);
      Map.layers().add(dot);
      Map.unlisten();
    });
  },
  });

var pathBtn = ui.Button({
  label: 'Caculating min cost path...',
  onClick: minCostPath,
  disabled: true // Keep disabled until there are two points selected
});

var panel = ui.Panel([selectPoints,pathBtn]);
panel.style().set({
  width: '250px',
  position: 'bottom-left'
});

Map.add(panel);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/390262b9baa019b959c42748020457ee

Comment: Thank you very much for your instruction!